# Enable\Disable commandbutton depending on URL parameter

Tags: jsf, disabled-control, viewparams

JSF 2 allows to init URL parameter using `<f:viewParam>` tag.

For example:

```
<f:viewParam id="name" name="name"
            value="#{applicationBean.name}" required="true" />
```

and then use this parameter in the backing bean to load some objects using `<f:event>`.

For example:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{applicationBean.preRenderView}" />
```

The `preRenderView()` method in `applicationBean` sets some boolean variable `buttonEnabled` to either true\false

When using this variable in the main page to enable\disable button it doesn't work (e.g it always evaluates to false):

```
<h:commandButton disabled="#{!applicationBean.buttonEnabled}">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Given that you're calling a bean method isn't the variable also in a bean? `#{applicationBean.buttonEnabled}`

Comment: I'm already using the bean variable. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a timing problem. The action event is queued during apply request values phase. It will as part of safeguard against tampered requests also evaluate the `disabled` (and `rendered`) attribute at that point. However, as it's only actually set right before the render response phase, then it will indeed always evaluate to its default value, which is apparently `false`.

You need to either perform the request parameter based initialization job in the `@PostConstruct` instead (the `<f:viewParam>` is then indeed insuitable), or to let the `disabled` attribute check the request parameter itself instead of a bean property (the bean property is then indeed insuitable).